# Sonata Admin Bundle Show Child table list along with Add/Edit screen of parent table

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am working with Sonata admin bundle and Symfony2.3.3. I have a parent table and a child table which has a foreign key linked. I have managed to create an 'Add new entry' button for the child table in the Parent admin's add/edit screen using the 'sonata_type_collection'. I want to know if it is possible to show the child table list in the same add/edit screen of the parent admin. I googled much but couldn't find a proper answer. I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 ->add('child', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position'
 ))
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Now I have the child table also listed and also I have a Add new button to add child table entries. But on clicking that I get an error. "Neither the property "abcd" nor the methods "__set()" or "__call()" exists and have public access in class ". What could possibly be the reason. I am also able to edit the child table separately

Comment: little late, but just in case someone else wonders about this: you need to create/generate an Admin Class for the child entity and remove the id field from the form via "configureFormFields" ...